# hiding H5 in bootstrap on mobile

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table in bootstrap, When viewed in mobile devices I only want H3 visible and if it clicked then the H5 becomes visible? I have posted this before but dont think i was clear enough. The code is below and its using bootstrap. Many thanks

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2"><h3><strong>Executive hire</strong></h3>        <h5>Mercedes<br>Bently<br>Rolls Royce<br>Jaguar<br>Range Rover<br>BMW<br>Audi</h5></div>
<div class="col-sm-2"><h3>Coach Hire</h3><h5>24 Seater coach<br />29 Seater coach<br />33 Seater coach<br />49 Seater coach<br />51 Seater coach<br />53 Seater coach<br />61 Seater coach<br />87 Seater coach</h5></div>
<div class="col-sm-2"><h3>Limo Hire</h3><h5>White Limo<br />Black Limo<br />Pink Limo<br />Hummer Limo<br />Fire Engine Limo<br />Jeep &amp; Novelty Limo</h5></div>

<div class="col-sm-2"><h3>Minibus Hire</h3><h5>10 Seater minibus<br />11 Seater minibus<br />12 Seater minibus<br />14 Seater minibus<br />14 Seater minibus<br />15 Seater minibus<br />16 Seater minibus</h5></div>

<div class="col-sm-2"><h3>Services</h3><h5>Private & Corporate Travel<br />Local & National Journeys<br />Airport Transfers<br />Sporting Events<br />Weddings<br />Theatre Trips<br />Stag & Hen Parties</h5></div>

<div class="col-sm-2"><h3>AREAS COVERED</h3></div>
```

Comment: **Do not** repost questions. If your previous question wasn't clear enough, clarify it with the "edit" link.

Comment: thats great, exacly what i wanted, is there any way to highlight as links when in mobile? thanks